# Store credentials for third party application

Tags: mysql, security, credentials, password-protection, password-hash

The application i am working on is going to log in users to a third party application (at so far as i am concered arbitrary times) automatically, using credentials that a user has provided us previousely. The credentials are going to be stored persistently using mysql. What are some options to make the storage more secure? I'd like to avoid storing them in plaintext but at the same time they can't be obscured at the time of login.

Comment: You can encrypt the passwords and store the encryption string in the database. When you need the password, retrieve it from the database and decrypt it. There are several methods of encrypting depending on the programming language you are using. Note that encryption is different from hashing. A Hash cannot be reversed, which is what you want to get the plain text password.

Comment: Have you investigated whether this third-party application offers some kind of single-signon capability? That is far more secure than storing usable passwords to the third party app.